# how to get text from a prompt warning in selenium java that disappears once I clicked on it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

How can I get the text inside this message before it disappears

Comment: this might be able to help: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/verify-tooltip-in-selenium#:~:text=To%20access%20or%20verify%20static,an%20expected%20value%20for%20verification.

Answer (score 1):

The message that is shown is from html 5 validation constraint

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-required-attribute

**so what you have to validate whether the required field is there and it was triggered**

### An example html:

```html
    <form>
      <label for="choose">Would you prefer a banana or a cherry?</label>
      <input id="choose" name="i_like" required pattern="[Bb]anana|[Cc]herry">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

### The java selenium code to check this message:

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/prave/Desktop/push.html");
    WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.id("choose"));
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
    field.sendKeys("sdasd");
    button.click();
    
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
    
    //this will print the entire validity object shows which validity failed
    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].validity",field));

    //shows true if no validity failed else false if any failed
    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].validity.valid",field));
    
    //shows the validityErorMessage that would be shown
    System.out.println(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].validationMessage",field));
```